# Defining sets C++

Tags: c++, c, parsing, syntax

I'm implementing a syntax analyzer for Clite as a Programming Languages class assignment. 
I'm using a recursive descent parser with a match() function that takes a string from an input scanner as an argument and checks if it is the expected token, else it returns an error message.

I've been trying to declare a set for the alphabet so I don't have to match each letter of the alphabet. Something like this:

```
void letter(){
    if(currentToken==LETTER){
        match(LETTER);
    }
    else
        error();
}
```

I tried with #define but realized it wasn't working

```
#define LETTER "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

Also tried with union or typedef but couldn't do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/

int isalpha ( int c );

Check if character is alphabetic

Also, check out the related functions: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/

By the way, what you were trying would never work, because

1) == does not attempt to do things like 'is contained by' 'is subset of' etc, but demands that both its operands compare equal.

2) The #define you are doing is not defining an array, or a container, or any other kind of data structure, so why would it work? You can look into std::set if you ever need to do this.

Comment: thanks for the tip, so how could I implement something like 'is contained by'

Comment: @Mario Montoya Use std::set (if you will be making many comparisons against a collection) or strchr/strstr (if you will only be making one, e.g. to avoid the overhead of needing to make it into a collection)

Comment: I resolved my problem with strbrk creating a char array key and comparing my input with it.If my input is contained in the key it returns true. 
Thanks for the help